# What is the lifetime of an x-ray binary?

Tags: binary-star, x-ray

What would be the typical lifetime of an x-ray binary? I have trouble finding a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on the topic but probably you have to specify in your search which mass regime are you looking for (low or high mass x-ray binaries). Accretion time must be important and depends on the mass. High-mass stars are young (very short life) < $10^7$ years. This reference is quite old but probably helps a bit:

- [The Average X-Ray Lifetime of Massive X-Ray Binaries](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1986IAUS..116..383H/0000383.000.html)
- [Observations of accretion disks in X-ray binaries](http://cds.cern.ch/record/363875/files/9809028.pdf)
- [X-Ray Binaries](http://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Epodsi/lec_c1_4_c.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of an X-ray binary is pretty broad and it depends on the type of X-ray binary you are talking about. There are 3 main types of X-ray binaries:

1. Low Mass X-ray Binaries
2. Intermediate Mass X-ray Binaries
3. High Mass X-ray Binaries

The accretion process is drastically different for each of these types, which means that there is no broad lifetime of an X-ray binary: it depends on the type of X-ray binary you are talking about.

I believe High Mass X-ray Binaries last the longest, give their comparatively lower accretion rate, but again, this is influenced by a wide range of parameters, like the age of the donor star.

In conclusion, the lifetime depends on the type of the X-ray binary, accretion rate, and other parameters.